# How do I change the model reference in one view from a seperate view? SwiftUI

Tags: swift, model-view-controller, swiftui, foreach

How do I change the data model of View A from View B? For instance, I have an App that uses multiple views.

[image: View A is a separate SwiftUI View with a list of buttons, and View B is another SwiftUI View]

I have a ForEach list of Buttons representing different types of Ice Cream and would like to use these buttons to change View B (model data).
What kind of tool should I look into trying?

```
ForEach(model.icecreams) { item in
                        ZStack {
                            Rectangle()
                                .foregroundColor(Color("Celadon"))
                            VStack {
                                Image(systemName: "sun.min")
                                    .font(.system(size: geo.size.width/4))
                                    .foregroundColor(Color("Thulian pink"))
                                    .padding(.bottom)
                                Text(item.name)
                                    .font(.largeTitle)
                                Text("$ \(String(format: "%.2f", item.available.price))")
                                    .font(.title)
                                    .bold()
                                    
                            }
                        }
                        .cornerRadius(30)
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width / 1.6, height: 380)
                    }
```

model.icecreams is the data I would like to manipulate so that when a button from View A is selected View B changes accordingly.

Comment: Have a look at this link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app 
[Managing model data in your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for bindings, e.g.

```
ForEach($model.icecreams) { $item in
```